# Express.js : how export an asynchronous result of a promise within my module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

Within my express.js app I've 2 modules:

the first is an initializer module, which I call at the beginning of the second; the main module.:

**mainModule.js**

```
const result = require('initilalizerModule')
...
```

**initilalizerModule.js:**

```
const soap = require('soap');
const path = require('path');

//passed en params for DAO
const endpoint = 'https://myurl.com';

const url = path.resolve(__dirname, 'mycontract.wsdl');
const soapOptions = {
    forceSoap12Headers: true,
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    disableCache: false
};

function initialize() {
    console.log("test") 
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
         soap.createClient(url, soapOptions, function (err, RESULT) {
            if (err) {
                reject('err');
            }
            else {
                client.setEndpoint(endpoint);
                resolve(RESULT);
            }
        });
    })
}

module.exports =  {
    myResult : ....
}
```

I have this asynchronous `initialize()` method which brings a `RESULT`

My purpose is how to export this `RESULT` object from my `initilizerModule` to be used after that in my `mainModule`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand async programming. require is synchronous and cached by default. Anything that you want to perform after some task async. You have to use the callback. Here is a basic example.

// main.js

```
const {init} = require("./provider")
init((data) => {
    console.log(data) // somedata
})
```

//provider.js

```
const someDelay = () => new Promise(r => {
    setTimeout(() => r("somedata"), 1000)
})
exports.init = (cb) => {
    someDelay().then(cb)
}
```

If you are using the lastest node.js. You can use async/await.
**async/await version**

// main.js

```
const {init} = require("./provider")
async function start() {
    const data = await init()
    console.log(data) // somedata
}
start()
```

// provider.js

```
const someDelay = () => new Promise(r => {
    setTimeout(() => r("somedata"), 1000)
})
exports.init = async () => {
    return await someDelay()
}
```

Hope this will answer your question! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

On a quick look you can define your `initialize()` function as a variable, which you can export, e.g. `const myResult = function initialize() {...`

and then use

```
module.exports =  { myResult }
```